# Append to Typescript interface properties

Tags: typescript

I have an API response like this:

```
{
  gender: 1,
  gender@formattedValue: "Male",
  category: 4,
  category@formattedValue: "Employee"
}
```

So it has lots of properties that are appended a `@formattedValue`.

Is it possible to create a typescript interface that automatically adds to every property `@formattedValue`? Of course leaving the original in tact, so intellisense shows both versions?

Comment: No, it isn't possible; [concatenating string literals is not implemented](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12940)

Comment: @OliverRadini thanks, so it means i have to manually add to all of them?

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I can tell at the moment, it would mean that; it may be possible to do this by having a tool which searches for interfaces and creates a new interface with the additional adjusted properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, you can't define interfaces with computed properties.